# C++ static variable produces a fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, static-variables

I am new to C++ and I am trying to learn the different uses of static keyword, I read that one of them is to define a static variable inside a class and call it using the scope operator. I tried to used that but Visual Studio 2012 produce an linking error. My code is:

```
class Vehicle
{
public:
    Vehicle(){};
    ~Vehicle(){};
    static int temp;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    Vehicle::temp=100;

    std::cout << Vehicle::temp << std::endl;

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And the error is:

**1>LearningC++.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int        Vehicle::temp" (?temp@Vehicle@@2HA)**

**1>c:\users\avraam\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\LearningC++\Debug\LearningC++.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals**

What may cause this problem?

***Edit1 (to make it more clear):***

My question is how can I access a static variable declared inside a class? Is this possible without using a member function?

Comment: You need to define the variable. Add `int Vehicle::temp;` after the class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `temp`, add this after `class Vechicle`:

```
class Vehicle
{
// Left out class code for brevity
   void useTemp() { temp = 200 ; } // Adding method inside class the uses temp
};

int Vehicle::temp = 0 ;
```

Note, you do not need `static` keyword when you define `temp`. Since it is `static` you do not need an instance of the class to access the variable, so the code you had in `main` is correct:

```
Vehicle::temp=100;

std::cout << Vehicle::temp << std::endl;

Vehicle v1 ;
v1.useTemp() ;

std::cout << Vehicle::temp << std::endl;
```

Comment: @AvraamMavridis I added some more details which hopefully makes it clear how to use `temp` inside and outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `static` member outside the class:

```
#include <iostream>

class Vehicle
{
  public:
     Vehicle(){};
    ~Vehicle(){};
    static int temp;
};

int Vehicle::temp = 0; 

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Vehicle::temp = 100;  //^^access the variable with classname plus ::
    std::cout << Vehicle::temp << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

then access it in `main` with classname followed by `::` and variable name.

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly what do you mean? I assign value to it inside main. It is OK not to give initial value when define it outside class.

Comment: Now it looks a lot better, if you don't initialize it outside and then by used it by mistake you will have a random value. (the value that was in the memory) so it is wise to initialize it outside.